# TypeError: fn is not a function at completeOutstandingRequest in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I am new to anugular js and working on simple module i.e Image Slider.

In this module, I have just change the image on home page. Everything is working fine. But now, I want to use some animation like when display next image then the previous image will be hide with fading effect.

To use animation, I have used angular animate plugin. When I include this plugin into m app, then browser show the error as given below:

```
TypeError: fn is not a function
at angular.js:16299
at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:4924)
at angular.js:5312
```

My custom Image sliding JS is:

```
var ps_mobile_app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);
ps_mobile_app.directive('slider', function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        images: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.currentIndex = 0;

        scope.next = function() {
            scope.currentIndex < scope.images.length - 1 ? scope.currentIndex++ : scope.currentIndex = 0;
        };

        scope.prev = function() {
            scope.currentIndex > 0 ? scope.currentIndex-- : scope.currentIndex = scope.images.length - 1;
        };

        scope.$watch('currentIndex', function() {
            scope.images.forEach(function(image) {
                image.visible = false;
            });
            scope.images[scope.currentIndex].visible = true;
        });

        /* Start: For Automatic slideshow*/

        var timer;

        var sliderFunc = function() {
            timer = $timeout(function() {
                scope.next();
                timer = $timeout(sliderFunc, 5000);
            }, 5000);
        };

        sliderFunc();

        scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            $timeout.cancel(timer);
        });

        /* End : For Automatic slideshow*/
    },
    templateUrl: 'shared/image-slider/slider.html'
}
```

});

My Image Slider module html is:

```
<div class="slider">  
 <div class="slide" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-show="image.visible">  
  <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" />  
 </div>  
 <div class="arrows">  
  <a href="#" ng-click="prev()">  
    <img src="shared/image-slider/img/left-arrow.png" />  
  </a>  
  <a href="#" ng-click="next()">  
    <img src="shared/image-slider/img/right-arrow.png" />  
  </a>  
 </div>  
</div>
```

I am using the above module in m home page:

```
<slider images="slider_images" />
```

With above code image slider is working fine without using Angular Animate plugin. But with Angular Animate, I am getting this error.  After little analysis I think that it is happening because of timeout function.

Can anyone please help me on this issue?  Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try

```html
var sliderFunc = function() {
            timer = $timeout(function() {
                scope.next;
                timer = $timeout(sliderFunc, 5000);
            }, 5000);
        };
```